# What is a natural guitar?

Tags: guitar

I did a Google search for natural acoustic guitar but no relevant results. It looks like electric guitars can be natural too. What does the term “natural” mean when it comes to guitars?

Comment: Where have you come across "natural guitar"? It sounds like you are talking about guitars with a natural finish (as opposed to sunburst or tobacco burst finishes).

Comment: Nothing... "Natural" means nothing.  Maybe you mean traditional?  Like the classical guitar family.

Comment: No GMO wood was used.  #itsajokedammmit

Comment: @DavidBowling Thank you for your response. I believe Todd answered my question below but here is an example: https://www.amazon.com/Jasmine-S35-Acoustic-Guitar-Natural/dp/B0002F58TG

Comment: @ggcg I think it refers to the finish as mentioned below

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's just a finish. A "natural" finish is basically clear, meaning you see the natural color of the wood. No stain or burst or anything, just a clear, usually glossy, coating.

Comment: Generally used when the wood is excellent in texture and markings. Otherwise cover it with a solid colour.

Comment: Just to add that many, usually cheaper, 'natural' guitars can have a thin veneer of pretty wood covering a multi-part and unmatched wood body. A natural finish doesn't mean that you are always getting a guitar made from the choicest cuts of wood.